# Как убрать лимит по объему при импорте БД в PHPmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. Хочу протестировать сайт, скачал по фтп его и базу данных. (БД весит 64 мб). Хочу импортировать БД у себя на локальном PHPmyAdmin, выдает ошибку "Вероятно, размер загружаемого файла слишком велик. Способы обхода данного ограничения описаны в документации." Документация не открывается.

Были ли у вас такие случаи? как обойти такую проблему что бы загрузить БД 64 мб.

Comment: Когда-нибудь Вам потребуется залить дамп в несколько Гб весом, и он никак не сможет пролезть через HTTP - ограничение протокола, однако.

Comment: Согласен! Решил проблему утилитой sypexdumper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

загружать дампы надо с помощью консольной утилиты `mysql`, которая обрабатывает файлы любого объема. Надо найти в своем Виндоуз программу mysql.exe и выполнить команду

```
mysql < dump.sql
```

по необходимости указав пути к обоим файлам.

Comment: не подскажите, как этим пользоваться на сервере? Т.е. прописать путь к файлу импорта и он создаст новую БД ?

Answer (score 2):

upload_max_filesize и post_max_size в php.ini надо поправить, если я ничего не путаю.